# Cannot load assemblies ( windows 7 visual studio 2010 )

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I loaded some old assemblies in my project yesterday and now when i cannot load them, they appear with a yellow mark on them in the references.
I have no idea what the hell i am doing wrong.
I really need some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open the Property Toolwindow and click (select) the assmeblies in referneces that show up with a yellow mark, you will see an entry in the property toolwindow for `Path`. This is the path that Visual Studio is using to locate the assembly. If the assembly doesn't exist there - you'll get this kind of error.

To fix the problem, either:

1. place a copy of the assembly at the location where VS is searching ... or
2. remove ad re-add the reference from the correct location.

Comment: Problem solved...i did nothing..i referenced the assembly only from the folder Dependencies of the project and the assembly was there. I am very confused. Your post is very useful for amateurs like me. Thanks you.

Answer (score 1):

when they appear with the yellow mark it means they cannot be found, look at their properties and check that they exist in the place they should. if they dont then re-reference them from another place they exist